# Kirk's formula when strike is negative

Tags: spread-options

Does anyone have experience with pricing spread options with potentially negative strike using Kirk's approximation?

I always see Kirk's price approximation used for positive strikes, but as far as I can see from the derivation/logic it does not preclude negative strikes as long as it is small compared to one of the asset prices. Is this right?

Comment: Can you write out the specific payoff of your spread option? Depending on the sign of strike, it should be added to the respective asset price to maintain the positivity.

Comment: @Gordon Ah, of course! I think I see what you mean. So for $K>0$ if the payoff is $(S1 - S2 - K)_+$ then I approximate $S_2 + K$ as lognormal, and if the payoff is $(S1 - S2 + K)_+$ which can be considered as a negative strike spread option, then I approximate $S1 + K$ as lognormal. And then use Margrabe formula. Correct?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant.